# How to append to each div only once

Tags: jquery, append, each

I have a few divs of questions where a user will click either yes or no buttons and want the values of their clicks to be appended to an empty class that displays what they chose.

Each time I click yes or no, the value gets appended to every single question, so that at the bottom the values are displayed i.e., Yes No No No Yes. I want it so that only the value for that specific question is displayed.

What I have so far -

```
$(function() {
var answer = $(".answer");
answer.each(function(index) {
$(this).on("click", function(){
  var userAnswer = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var displayAnswer = $(".display-answer");
  displayAnswer.each(function() {
      $(this).append(userAnswer);
    });
   });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="question-wrap">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi. Similique dolorem modi quos eius in, unde, sapiente, non ipsa aliquam accusamus quis facilis enim.</p>
        <div class="answer-buttons">
            <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
            <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-answer"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: we would need to see how the html is structured to be able to help, but I'm guessing you have a "display-answer" div within or as a sibling for each "answer" div? If so, they may share the same index, in which case you could use `$(".display-answer").eq(index)` to fetch only the "display-answer" you need.

Comment: @MichaelBeeson HTML added (although it is all generated through js, that's how the markup would look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get the result you describe

```js
    $(function(){
     $(".answer").click(function(){ /*You can register the click handler easily in one step*/
       var userAnswer = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $(this).parent().siblings(".display-answer").append(userAnswer); /*First, find the parent, then the "display-answer" siblings*/
      });
    
    });
```

```css
p{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.answer{
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  flex-grow:100;
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi. Similique dolorem modi quos eius in, unde, sapiente, non ipsa aliquam accusamus quis facilis enim.</p>
    <div class="answer-buttons">
      <div class="answer yes" data-id="yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
      <div class="answer no" data-id="no"><p>No</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-answer"></div>
</div>
<div class="question-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi. Similique dolorem modi quos eius in, unde, sapiente, non ipsa aliquam accusamus quis facilis enim.</p>
    <div class="answer-buttons">
      <div class="answer yes" data-id="yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
      <div class="answer no" data-id="no"><p>No</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-answer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works well!

Answer (score 1):

A simple example, based on your markup:

```js
$('.answer').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().next().html($(this).html());
    // `$(this).html()` gets the html of an element you clicked on
    // `$(this).parent().next()` - gets `.display-answer` element which 
    // is located `next` to the `parent` of the element you clicked
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="question-wrap">
        <p>Question 1.</p>
        <div class="answer-buttons">
            <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
            <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-answer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="question-wrap">
        <p>Question 2.</p>
        <div class="answer-buttons">
            <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
            <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-answer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="question-wrap">
        <p>Question 3.</p>
        <div class="answer-buttons">
            <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
            <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="display-answer"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the html. It means we can help out!

U_mulder's answer will absolutely work, so long as the structure remains precisely the same. My suggestion of using index would not work because there are two "answer" classes per question.

In the snippet I've added here you'll see I use first `.parents(".question-wrap").eq(0)` to find the question-wrap div, then `.children(".display-answer").eq(0)` to find the display div. `.children()` only searches amongst an element's immediate children. If you need to look further down (the opposite of `parents()`), use `.find()`.

Here you'll see it in action (using `.text()` to get the value seeing as there is no data-id attribute)

```js
$(function() {
var answer = $(".answer");
answer.each(function(index) {
$(this).on("click", function(){
  var userAnswer = $(this).text();
  var displayAnswer = $(this).parents(".question-wrap").eq(0).children(".display-answer").eq(0);
  displayAnswer.text(userAnswer);
   });
  });
});
```

```css
.question-wrap {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.answer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.display-answer {
  height:20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgreen
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
<div class="question-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi.</p>
    <div class="answer-buttons">
        <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
        <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-answer"></div>
</div>
<div class="question-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi.</p>
    <div class="answer-buttons">
        <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
        <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-answer"></div>
</div>

<div class="question-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi.</p>
    <div class="answer-buttons">
        <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
        <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-answer"></div>
</div>

<div class="question-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi.</p>
    <div class="answer-buttons">
        <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
        <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-answer"></div>
</div>

<div class="question-wrap">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, ea maxime velit hic tenetur, animi.</p>
    <div class="answer-buttons">
        <div class="answer yes"><p>Yes</p></div>
        <div class="answer no"><p>No</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="display-answer"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Another great solution.